# delete button y addButton

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a website where you can save and delete times. At the beginning I can save. But when I delete, I delete all times and can no longer save anything. Also, when I reload the page, what I deleted is back. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```js
function deleteWorktime() {
    let myWorkingHours = document.getElementById("myWorkingHours");
    myWorkingHours.parentNode.removeChild(myWorkingHours)
}

function sicherheitsabfrage(){
    confirm(message)
}

myWorkingHours.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('html');

function addWorktime() {

    let currentDate = myDate.value;
    let startTime = myStartTime.value;
    let endTime = myEndTime.value;

    myWorkingHours.innerHTML +=
        `<div class="list-item">
    <img class="small-img" src="img/Uhr.png">
    ${currentDate} ${startTime} - ${endTime} 
    </div>`;

    localStorage.setItem('html', myWorkingHours.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

#addbutton {
  background-color: rgb(7, 158, 240);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#deletebutton{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


input {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
}

.list-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 60;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.small-img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Arbeitszeiten</h1>
<input id="myDate" placeholder="Datum einfügen" type="date">
<input id="myStartTime" placeholder="Startzeit einfügen" type="time">
<input id="myEndTime" placeholder="Endzeit einfügen" type="time">
<button id="addbutton" onclick="addWorktime()">Speichern</button>
<button id="deletebutton" onclick="deleteWorktime()" onclick="sicherheitsabfrage()"> Alle Arbeitszeiten löschen</button>
<div id="myWorkingHours"></div>
```

I have search 3 hours, but with not results

Comment: You have two `onclick` attributes for `#deletebutton`.

Comment: Could the problem be that `message` is undefined in `sicherheitsabfrage()`? Have you checked your developer console for errors?

Comment: Yes but it has no errors

Comment: I got `myWorkingHours is not defined`; it's scoped to `deleteWorktime()`.

Comment: I have got create a variable, but it was of no use

Comment: Create it outside of the function so it's not scoped to that function.

Comment: I have this error in the console : Uncaught TypeError: myWorkingHours.parentNode is null
    deleteWorktime http://127.0.0.1:5500/www/script.js:5
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/www/index.html:1
script.js:5:5
    deleteWorktime http://127.0.0.1:5500/www/script.js:5
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/www/index.html:1

Comment: I haven't seen that, but try [remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) instead?

Comment: Ok I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deleteWorktime` is currently removing the entire `myWorkingHours` from the DOM, which is why you can't save anything after deleting. Instead, you should clear the innerHTML of the `myWorkingHours` to remove all the saved times. Also, the data is not persisting after a page reload because `myWorkingHours.innerHTML` is not being set from localStorage when the page loads. You need to retrieve the saved HTML from localStorage and set it as the innerHTML of `myWorkingHours` when the page loads. Lastly, `sicherheitsabfrage` is not defined correctly. It should be a confirmation dialog that asks the user if they are sure they want to delete all times.

```js
// Retrieve saved times from localStorage when the page loads
window.onload = function() {
    let myWorkingHours = document.getElementById("myWorkingHours");
    myWorkingHours.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('html') || '';
}

function deleteWorktime() {
    let myWorkingHours = document.getElementById("myWorkingHours");
    // Clear the innerHTML of the myWorkingHours div
    myWorkingHours.innerHTML = '';
    // Remove the saved times from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('html');
}

function sicherheitsabfrage() {
    let confirmDelete = confirm('Möchten Sie wirklich alle Arbeitszeiten löschen?');
    return confirmDelete ? deleteWorktime() : null;
}

function addWorktime() {
    let myWorkingHours = document.getElementById("myWorkingHours");
    let currentDate = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
    let startTime = document.getElementById("myStartTime").value;
    let endTime = document.getElementById("myEndTime").value;

    myWorkingHours.innerHTML +=
        `<div class="list-item">
            <img class="small-img" src="img/Uhr.png">
            ${currentDate} ${startTime} - ${endTime}  
        </div>`;

    localStorage.setItem('html', myWorkingHours.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}

#addbutton {
    background-color: rgb(7, 158, 240);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#deletebutton{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
}

.list-item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 60;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.small-img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Arbeitszeiten</h1>
<input id="myDate" placeholder="Datum einfügen" type="date">
<input id="myStartTime" placeholder="Startzeit einfügen" type="time">
<input id="myEndTime" placeholder="Endzeit einfügen" type="time">
<button id="addbutton" onclick="addWorktime()">Speichern</button>
<button id="deletebutton" onclick="sicherheitsabfrage()"> Alle Arbeitszeiten löschen</button>
<div id="myWorkingHours"></div>
```